# I'm using the latest version of the Facebook PHP SDK and i'm receiving an Exception sometimes, but why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the latest version of the Facebook PHP SDK,

"require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
  }

Below is my php object that handles and makes the calls using the facebook php sdk.

http://pastebin.com/3hiC8V8z

My script works fine normally whenever i pass in any facebook user id to it in the Posted $_POST['selected_uid'] parameter. However, If i pass in my own ID as the posted 'selected_uid' parameter, I receive the following error message.

2015-03-09T20:33:44.302608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/fb/fetchUserData.php" host=graffiti-galore.herokuapp.com request_id=19d11e60-8441-41be-8cb5-2018ce8602e4 fwd="67.225.25.80" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=124ms status=500 bytes=228
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548611+00:00 app[web.1]: [09-Mar-2015 20:33:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at LINK REMOVED' in /app/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:104
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548617+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548619+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(280): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400)
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548627+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 /app/web/fb/fetchUserData.php(148): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute()
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548628+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 /app/web/fb/fetchUserData.php(109): FetchUserData->fetchDrawings()
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548630+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 /app/web/fb/fetchUserData.php(21): FetchUserData->__construct()
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548632+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 {main}
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548633+00:00 app[web.1]:   thrown in /app/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 104
2015-03-09T20:33:44.548635+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.51.168.187 - - [09/Mar/2015:20:33:44 +0000] "POST /fb/fetchUserData.php HTTP/1.1" 500 1 "LINK REMOVED" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0

Why does my script work fine whenever it's another user on facebook, but i receive this error message when the selected_uid is the app users.

Comment: So you are passing in user ids that you get from somewhere external? Then my guess would be that your app is simply not allowed to read data using that id. You are aware of the concept of app-scoped user ids that API v2 introduced, right?

Comment: I resolved this problem by doing some debugging. Turns out the selected_uid parameter was null LOL. Yes i am now aware of the app-scoped user ids in v2 of fb graph API